# Curlier mathcal?

Tags: fonts, mathcal

In my LaTeX document, `$\mathcal{N}$` is not being rendered 'curly' enough for my liking:

[image]

If my document class is 'article' then I get the curlier N. The problem occurs when my document class is 'elsarticle' (Elsevier template). Presumably there's something that I can override?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [mathalfa package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa) by Michael Sharpe? On pp. 6f. of the package's user guide you'll find listings of the looks of a couple dozen math-calligraphic alphabets. The broad subcategories are "upright", "restrained", "embellished", and "heavily sloped". I trust one of them will meet your needs

Comment: Further to the list of math calligraphic fonts featured in the `mathalfa` package: It looks like you (or the document class you use) may be loading either the `mma` ("Mathematica Script") or the `pxtx` (times) font package. The math calligraphic font you say you want indeed appears to be the regular Computer Modern math calligraphic alphabet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Mico had guessed, and you'd verified, you were loading non-standard calligraphic fonts in your document. By leaving the class options as default, or by adding the `times` option, you get two different results:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[times]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{N}$
\end{document}
```

by default:

[image]

with `times`:

[image]

Comment: Aha! The problem was that I had [times] before {elsarticle} - thank you. I'm not sure what to do now - do I delete the question? Leave it? Or do you want to update your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: I'll clean up the answer a bit. If someone in the management thinks the question should be deleted, I'm sure they'll say something.